# Loading many flatfiles into SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, etl

I have a very annoying task. I have to load >100 CSV-files from a folder to SQL Server database. The files have column names in first row. Data type can be varchar for all columns. The table names in database can just be filename of the CSVs. What I am currently doing is that I use Import/Export Wizard from SSMS, I choose flatfile from dropdown box, choose the file, next->next->next and finish! Any ideas how can I automate such a task in Integration services or with any other practical method?

Note: Files are on my local PC, DB-server is somewhere else, so I cannot use BULK INSERT.

Comment: Hmm just write a little c# tool that pumps the data into the database. you might use something like this to do so... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx.

Comment: Or check out  http://www.filehelpers.com  for a great C# library to load text files and process them

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSIS - Foeach loop container to extract file names - by arranging to particular format.Use a variable to dynamically fill the variable with file name.Then in dataflowtask , use flat file source for source - oledb destination.

Please post some sample file names.so that i can learn and guide you properly.

Thanks

Achudharam